# Как сохранять данные store по уникальному ключу в localSorage с помощью инструментариев Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, localstorage

Требуется для каждого уникального пользователя сохранять свои данные фильтрации. Менеджером локлального хранилища я использую redux и мне интересно, можно ли сохранить store по уникальному ключу и доставать его под конкретного пользака. Знаю про redux-persist и видел в конфиге keyPrefix, но не совсем понял как им пользоваться инструментарием самой библиотеки исмущает что в будущем планируется от него отказ.

Могу без проблем и сам сделать механизм сохранния в локальное хранилище, но интересно какие есть еще возможные инструментарии, либо как в persist достать данные по keyPrefix

Comment: Какую задачу вы хотите решить? Сохранением данных в localStorage вы решите только проблему сохранением каких то данных в конкретном браузере. Этот же пользователь, зайдя в другом браузере или на другом устройстве, сохренное не увидит.

Comment: @SwaD Мне нужно именно в браузере у конкретного человека, человек может сидеть под несколькими учетками пользаков

Comment: Ну тогда, как видится, локальное хранилище(не, ну конечно можно задействовать indexDB...), то что вам нужно.